# Plug $2m≥5f$ into $m-n+f=2$ and simplify

Tags: algebra-precalculus

> Plug $2m≥5f$ into $m-n+f=2$ and simplify

It is a question on Euler's formula but I can't seem to simplify it when I try to add the inequality to Euler's formula.

Answer (score 1):

If $2m\ge 5f$, then $m\ge\frac52f$, and $$2=m-n+f\ge\frac52f-n+f=\frac72f-n\;.$$ That is,

$$\frac72f-n\le 2\;,$$ or $7f-2n\le 4$, or $7f\le 2n+4$, or whatever equivalent form seems most useful or convenient.

Alternatively, you could write $f\le\frac25m$, infer that

$$2=m-n+f\le m-n+\frac25m=\frac75m-n\;,$$

and simplify to an inequality involving just $m$ and $n$.